# Back button in IE 11 clearing form

Tags: html, internet-explorer, asp-classic, internet-explorer-11

How do I stop IE 11 (Version: 11.0.0600.17280, Update Versions: 11.0.12) from clearing form data when the user uses the back button?

I have several pages generated from Perl ASP (classic) that have worked as desired for ~15 years.  Something has changed in IE11 that is causing **back** to clear the forms.  Chrome and Firefox still work as desired.

```
<%@ LANGUAGE=PerlScript %>
<%Response->{CacheContorl} = "Private";
Response->{Expires} = 15; %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<META http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META http-equiv="expires" CONTENT="Fri, 1 Jan 2002 01:00:00 GMT">

<form method="POST" name="aform" ACTION="<%= $ACTION %>">
```

Comment: have you tried all the obvious first checks such as adding the website to trusted security zone and lowering the security fully, unchecking "do not save encrypted pages to disk" etc.?

Comment: "do not save encrypted pages to disk" was not checked.  I can change the individual security settings, but not the group (corporate policy).  I moved all to the lowest security setting and still have the same behavior.

Comment: It could be that it has actually cached the form as empty. You tried clearing temp files and cookies and trying again?

Comment: I don't think so.  We have several separate form pages and they are all exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: Can you send a link to one of the forms or are they all local?
I've got IE11 here too, I can test to see if it's an issue with your machine or the browser.

Comment: It is local, so that won't work.  A second issue of periods being swapped to underscores for downloads also exists. Removing and re-installing fixed the problems for a day.  There may have been a corporate security patch installed overnight that broke it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second issue of periods being swapped to underscores for downloads also started.  It turns out removing and re-installing fixed the problems.